# How exactly are holomorphic maps with hyperkahler targets identified as triholomorphic maps?

Tags: complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hyperkaehler

In Appendix A of [Hyperinstantons, the Beltrami Equation, and Triholomorphic Maps](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09056.pdf) by Fre et al., it is described how holomorphic maps from a Riemann surface to a hyperkahler manifold $\mathcal{N}$,  can be understood as triholomorphic maps (also known as hyperinstantons) from a hyperkahler 4-manifold $\mathcal{M}_4$ to $\mathcal{N}$.

In particular, it was shown (c.f. equations A.10 and A.11) that these triholomorphic maps take the form

\begin{eqnarray}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  \partial_{\bar{\alpha}} \, q^i &=& 0 \label{holomorfo} \tag{A.10}\\
 \partial_\alpha \, q^i &=& \, - \,{\rm i} \, \frac{1}{2} \, \epsilon_{\alpha}^{\phantom{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}\,
 \partial_{\bar{\beta}} \, \bar{q}^{\bar{\ell}} \, \bar{\Omega}_{\bar{\ell}}^{\phantom{\ell}i} \tag{A.11}
 \label{triholomorfo}
\end{eqnarray}
plus the complex conjugates of the above. The first equation says that $q^i$ is holomorphic w.r.t. the two complex coordinates of $\mathcal{M}_4$. The second constraint relates the holomorphic derivatives of
the holomorphic coordinates of $\mathcal{N}$ to the anti-holomorphic derivatives of the anti-holomorphic coordinates of $\mathcal{N}$ 
through the unique $Ω^{(2,0)}$ form of $\mathcal{N}$.

It is then claimed that if $q^i$
depends holomorphically only on ONE of the two coordinates of the base
manifold, then the triholomorphicity conditions above are automatically satisfied.

I can see this for A.10, but how is this true for A.11?